# How to add quotes to line break field values in a file

Tags: text-processing

Input file having and two records and three fields, second attribute contains new line characters.I want enclose every field value with double quotes.

### Input File:

```
100|Alert created becuase of high volume.
Money withdrawan more 5000.
Try to access acccount from unathorised devíce|2019-01-24
200|Minimum amount not avialable in your account.
Last time deposited amonut month ago|2019-01-24
```

### Required output should be like below

```
"100"|"Alert created becuase of high volume.
Money withdrawan more 5000.
Try to access acccount from unathorised devíce"|"2019-01-24"
"200"|"Minimum amount not avialable in your account.
Last time deposited amonut month ago"|"2019-01-24"
```

Comment: Are you able to modify the code or output format of whatever _produces_ this data?

Comment: Wait, so there are linebreaks in the delimited strings?!

Comment: Yes, OP says: `second attribute contains new line characters`.

Comment: @RoVo what is "second attribute" anyway?

Comment: You should ask OP ... but I guess it means *second field* of his `|sv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this awk :

```
awk -F'\n' '!f{$1="\""$1;f=1}{f=f+gsub("[|]","\"|\"")}f==3{$0=$0"\"";f=0}1' infile
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.it is working as expected. But it is not accepting when i tired to parameterized like this                                                                                                 
awk -F'\n' '!f{$1="\""$1;f=1}{f=f+gsub("[|]","\"|\"")}f==$Fieldcnt{$0=$0"\"";f=0}1'

Comment: @chavakumar Fieldcnt is not defined. If it's a shell variable : try to pass it to awk with -v.

Comment: I have tried with option -v and it was worked.  awk -v NOOFATTRIBUTES="$NOOFATTRIBUTES" -F'\n' '!f{$1="\""$1;f=1}{f=f+gsub("[|]","\"|\"")}f==NOOFATTRIBUTES{$0=$0"\"";f=0}1'

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `perl`:

```
perl -0pe 's/([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|\n]*)(\n|$)/"\1"|"\2"|"\3"\4/g' input_file
```

- `-0` read file at once, not line by line.
- `-p` print the line in the end
- `-e` the expression
- `s/pattern/replacement/g` Replace pattern with replacement

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat input.txt | tr "\n" "\t" \
  |awk -v FS="|" -v OFS="|" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i="\""$i"\"";}1' \
  |tr "\t" "\n"
```

- `tr` transform new line to a tab. So the input is linearized
- We tell `awk` to handle the `|` as a field seperator. Now we can iterat over each field and add the quotation marks around. Afterwards the whole line is printed
- `tr` converts the tab back to a new line

Comment: Thank you for help, but this code didnt work in my case.

Comment: "didn't work" is never a good error description. Could you please describe what doesn't work?

Comment: Hi, It is not generated any error but there is no change in output. Output is same as input.command used like this. cat filename.txt | tr "\n" "\t" |awk -v FS="|" -v OFS="|" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=""$i"";}1' |tr "\t" "\n"

Comment: Could you try my edited version?